# Integrating GULP with node.js

Tags: node.js, web-services, gulp, node-modules, gulp-rev

I have a project in node.js for which I want to automate some backup and revision tasks in GULP.

I am able to successfully test following gulp code in terminal and everything working perfectly. The issue comes when I run gulp task from node.js code.

**Gulp code:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var format = require('date-format');

var dt = (new Date());
var gBkup = __dirname + '/backup/' + format.asString('ddMMyyyy_hhmm', dt);
var config = __dirname + '/gHelper.json', mnf = __dirname + '/rev-manifest.json';

var cssSrc = [], cssSrcO = [], cssSrcI = [];
var dirSrc = [], dirSrcO = [], dirSrcI = [];

gulp.task('init', function (){      // Initialize paths and all arrays containing file paths
    var fexists = require('file-exists');
    //console.log('Config exists: ' + fexists(config));
    if (fexists(config)) {
        config = require(config);
    }

    //console.log('Config object: ' + config);

    if (fexists(mnf)) {
        mnf = require(mnf);
    }

    for (var file in config.revision.ext_css) {
        var fnm = __dirname + '/preview/' + config.revision.ext_css[file];
        cssSrc.push(fnm);

        if (mnf[config.revision.ext_css[file]] != "") {
            var hnm = __dirname + '/live/' + mnf[config.revision.ext_css[file]];
            cssSrcO.push(hnm);
            console.log("Manifest: " + hnm);
        }
    }

    for (var dir in config.revision.dir) {
        dirSrc.push(__dirname + '/preview/' + config.revision.dir[dir]);
        var dirnm = __dirname + '/live/' + config.revision.dir[dir];
        dirnm = dirnm.substr(0, dirnm.length-3);
        dirSrcO.push(dirnm);
        console.log("Directory: " + dirnm);
    }

    // Files and directories will be ignored in revision
    for (var file in config.revision.ext_css) {
        cssSrcI.push('!' + __dirname + '/preview/' + config.revision.ext_css[file]);
    }

    for (var dir in config.revision.dir) {
        dirSrcI.push('!' + __dirname + './preview/' + config.revision.dir[dir]);
    }

    //console.log('Ignore CSS: ' + cssSrcI);
    //console.log('Ignore DIR: ' + dirSrcI);
});

// Revisioning Files
gulp.task('revisionCSS', function() {       // Revise CSS scripts
  var cssDest = __dirname + config.revision.ext_css_dest;

  console.log('cssDestination: ' + cssDest);
  return gulp.src(cssSrc)
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest))
        .pipe(rev.manifest({base: cssDest, merge: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest))
});

gulp.task('revInnerScripts', function () {  // Revise javascripts
  var dirDest = __dirname + config.revision.ext_dir_dest;
  var cssDest = __dirname + config.revision.ext_css_dest;

  console.log('dirInner: ' + dirDest);
  console.log('cssInner: ' + cssDest);

  return gulp.src(dirSrc)
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dirDest))
        .pipe(rev.manifest({base: cssDest, merge: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});

gulp.task('copyIgnoreRevision', function() {    // Simply copy other/ignored files from array
    var src = [__dirname + '/preview/**']
    src = src.concat(cssSrcI);
    src = src.concat(dirSrcI);
    console.log(src)

    return gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + '/live'));
});

gulp.task('removeLive', function(callback) {    // Removing files
    var del = require('del');
    var src = cssSrcO.concat(dirSrcO);
    console.log("Removing Files: " + src);
    return del(src);
});

gulp.task('backupLive', function() {            // Backing up revision files before taking revision
//  var src = ['./Live/**'];
    gulp.src(cssSrcO).pipe(gulp.dest(gBkup));

    return gulp.src(dirSrcO).pipe(gulp.dest(gBkup + "/js"));;
/*  return gulp.src(cssSrcO, {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());*/

});

gulp.task('backup', function(callback) {        // Backup tasks list
    runSequence('backupLive', 'removeLive', callback);
});
gulp.task('revise', ['copyIgnoreRevision', 'revisionCSS', 'revInnerScripts']);
gulp.task('revback', function (callback) {
    runSequence('init', 'backup', 'revreplace', callback);
});

// Replacing references
gulp.task('revreplace', ['revise'], function(callback) {        // In callback replace references for revised files
    var revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
    var mReps = gulp.src(__dirname + '/rev-manifest.json');
    return gulp.src(__dirname + '/preview/*.html')
        .pipe(revReplace({manifest: mReps}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + '/live'));
});
```

**gHelper.json**: Listing files which needs to be revised. Everything else will be copied to destination directory.

```
{
  "revision": {
    "ext_css" : [
        "extie.css",
        "responsive.css",
        "style.css"
    ],
    "ext_css_dest": "/live",
    "dir": [
        "js/*.js"
    ],
    "ext_dir_dest": "/live/js"
  }
}
```

**Basic folder structure**:

```
MainFolder/
  gHelper.json
  gulpfile.js
  preview/
    HTML files which contains references to revision files
    Revision files (CSS and JS). CSS files are mentioned in gHelper.json
    js/
        Revision files (mainly js) which are to be revised as this folder is mentioned in gHelper.json and all files from the folder will be revised
```

When gulp task `revback` is invoked a folder `live` will be generated and added inside `MainFolder`. Again when `revback` is invoked, first, `backup/{timestamp}` folder will be generated taking backup of revised files only and then revision is made for `live` folder.

Lets see **code from Node.js**:

/*  Publish client  */

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
router.post('/api/:clientName/publish', function(req, res, next) {
    var clientName = req.params.clientName;
    var filePath = '/gulpfile'; // Full path for gulp file

    console.log("Publish client: " + filePath);
    try {
      var gtask = require(filePath);

      if (gulp.tasks.revback) {
          console.log('gulp file contains task!');
          gulp.start('revback');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
});
```

Now the problem comes that sometimes gulp tasks are not being completed, rev-manifest.json is not created at proper position means inside `MainFolder` but created outside in the folder where this node.js lies.

Please let me know how to resolve the issue, Thanks.

---

Below is content of **rev-manifest.json**:

```
{
  "dctConf.js": "dctConf-7c467cb7cb.js",
  "extie.css": "extie-a8724bfb0c.css",
  "responsive.css": "responsive-76492b9ad4.css",
  "style.css": "style-770db73beb.css",
  "translation.js": "translation-9687245bfb.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used gulp's native callbacks and removed run-sequence module.

E.g.:

```
gulp.task('revback', ['revise'], function(callback) {
    var revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
    var mReps = gulp.src(__dirname + '/rev-manifest.json');

    console.log('Manifest content: ' + mReps + ' && ' + __dirname + '/rev-manifest.json');

    return gulp.src(__dirname + '/preview/*.html')
        .pipe(revReplace({manifest: mReps}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + '/live'))
        .once('error', function(e) {
            console.log('Error at revback: ' + e);
            callback(e);
            process.exit(1);
        })
        .once('end', function() {
            console.log('Ending process at revback!');
            callback();
            process.exit();
        });
});

gulp.task('revise', ['copyIgnoreRevision', 'revisionCSS', 'revInnerScripts']);

gulp.task('backupLive', ['init'], function() {
//  var src = ['./Live/**'];
    gulp.src(cssSrcO).pipe(gulp.dest(gBkup));

    return gulp.src(dirSrcO).pipe(gulp.dest(gBkup + "/js"));
/*  return gulp.src(cssSrcO, {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());*/

});
```

This way, reverse chained to `init` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the working directory in your gulpfile.js to the location of the gulpfile. Just add this at the top

```
process.chdir(__dirname);
```

---

**Docs**

- https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory
- https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: Thanks @potatopeelings. This is working but it stopped the working of rev-replace. So, the last function in gulpfile.js which is revreplace is not replacing file references in HTML files. I have added contents of rev-manifest.json above. Please let me know what can be the possible solution to this.

Comment: I found the issue that callback for "rereplace" is not being called and thus rev-replace is not being in action. :(

Comment: Any hint here @potatopeelings?